# Magent 2 - Exception logs check

Tags: magento2, exception

In Magento 2 I got a message to check exception error logs. How can I check that?

Comment: you can check at magento2Root/var/log/exception.log

Comment: all exception log in the exception.log

Comment: Thanks for comments

Comment: welcome...... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to:

> Magento/var/log/exception.log

Comment: Thanks dude. That works